# How to insert Ansible std_outlines output JSON into MongoDB with Python

Tags: python, json, mongodb, ansible-facts

I am running the following task in my playbook

```
- name: get system info  
shell: uname -r  
register: uname_out  
- debug: var=uname_out  
when: conn_out is success  
- name: copy   
copy:  
  content={{ uname_out.stdout_lines }} dest={{inventory_hostname}}.json
```

I get the JSON output like this

```
["rhel", "linux", "7", "basevesrion"]
```

To insert this data into MongoDB, I am writing the script as follows

```
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient
fileName = "data.json"
print(fileName)

client = MongoClient('10.*.*.*',27017)
db = client['test']
collection_cmdbFact = db['facts']
with open(fileName,'r') as data_file:
  data_json = json.loads(data_file.read())
collection.insert_one(data_json)
client.close()
```

I am getting this error

> TypeError: document must be an instance of dict, bson.son.SON, bson.raw_bson.RawBSONDocument, or a type that inherits from collections.MutableMapping

Can someone tell me how do I insert this data?

Answer (score 0):

I ran a quick test.  This works fine:

```
collection.insert_one(json.loads("{\"a\":1}"))
```

While this returns the exact error you noted:

```
collection.insert_one(json.loads("[{\"a\":1},{\"a\":2}]"))
```

If your file contains an array of documents, you might need to use `insert_many`:

```
collection.insert_many(json.loads("[{\"a\":1},{\"a\":2}]"))
```